# How to reconnect to a persistence unit after an oracle Database failure

Tags: oracle, glassfish, eclipselink, glassfish-3

When I unfortunately need to restart my Oracle database (after a failure, or for any reason). My persistence unit cannot reconnect to the database (after it is up again).

Here is the error log :

```
           [#|2012-03-28T16:59:01.384+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/distriapps/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/distriapps/applications/SiteApplicationUpdater-Central/SAU-CommonFacade-ejb_jar/_SiteApplicationUpdater_PU|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|
  Local Exception Stack: 
  Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
  Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
  Error Code: 17008
  Call: SELECT t0.ID, t0.ADDRESS, t0.CITY, t0.COUNTRY, t0.DESCRIPTION, t0.EXHIBITORNAME, t0.GLASSFISHVERSION, t0.LASTSYNCTIMESTAMP, t0.LASTUPDATETIMESTAMP, t0.MACHINENAME, t0.OSARCH, t0.OSNAME, t0.OSVERSION, t0.SITEAPPLICATIONMACHINEID, t0.ZIPCODE FROM SAU_REPORTS t0 WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(t1.ID) FROM SAU_ISLINKS t1 WHERE (t1.SiteApplicationReport_id = t0.ID)) = ?)
bind => [1 parameter bound]
   Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=SiteApplicationReport sql="SELECT t0.ID, t0.ADDRESS, t0.CITY, t0.COUNTRY, t0.DESCRIPTION, t0.EXHIBITORNAME, t0.GLASSFISHVERSION, t0.LASTSYNCTIMESTAMP, t0.LASTUPDATETIMESTAMP, t0.MACHINENAME, t0.OSARCH, t0.OSNAME, t0.OSVERSION, t0.SITEAPPLICATIONMACHINEID, t0.ZIPCODE FROM SAU_REPORTS t0 WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(t1.ID) FROM SAU_ISLINKS t1 WHERE (t1.SiteApplicationReport_id = t0.ID)) = ?)")
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.processExceptionForCommError(DatabaseAccessor.java:1494)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:636)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:535)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1702)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:566)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:264)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:646)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2592)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2551)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:418)

at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1097)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:829)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1056)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:390)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1144)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2863)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1501)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.retryQuery(AbstractSession.java:1571)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.retryQuery(ClientSession.java:593)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.retryQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:5453)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1537)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.retryQuery(AbstractSession.java:1571)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.retryQuery(ClientSession.java:593)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.retryQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:5453)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1537)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.retryQuery(AbstractSession.java:1571)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.retryQuery(ClientSession.java:593)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.retryQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:5453)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1537)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.retryQuery(AbstractSession.java:1571)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.retryQuery(ClientSession.java:593)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.retryQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:5453)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1537)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1483)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1457)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.executeReadQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:485)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getResultList(EJBQueryImpl.java:742)
at com.xdcinema.siteapplicationupdater.commonfacade.SiteApplicationReportFacade.findUnlinkedSite(SiteApplicationReportFacade.java:275)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2440.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5366)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor164.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5338)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5326)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at $Proxy376.findUnlinkedSite(Unknown Source)
at com.xdcinema.siteapplicationupdater.centralserver.jsf.SiteApplicationReportController.getItems(SiteApplicationReportController.java:598)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor366.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:116)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:740)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1798)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:356)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:600)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:91)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1763)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:518)
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:1411)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1600)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1600)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:344)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1600)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1600)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:376)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:297)
at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:981)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:390)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:232)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3560)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.prepareStatement(ConnectionHolder.java:562)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:255)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:52)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnection.prepareCachedStatement(ManagedConnection.java:964)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:173)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1474)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1423)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:697)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:585)
... 125 more|#]
```

EclipseLink is used in a JDBC connection Pool with Glassfish 3.1.1 .
Do you know a convenient method for the pool to reconnect automatically after losing the connection to the database ?

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace. Which connection method do you use for EclipseLink (RESOURCE_LOCAL? internal/external connection pooling? etc.)

Comment: @MRalwasser : I just edited the question. I hope you have all the info now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is not caused by EclipseLink but by the glassfish connection pool which you use.

**The pool seems to be not aware** that its **connections** are **closed**/invalid and still returning them to your application/eclipselink.

I never configured this pool, but please consult the documentation how to **enable the keep alive/ verification** feature within the connection pool.
This will ensure that the pool will test idle connections periodically and remove/renew them in case they are detected as invalid/closed.